# Wordpress wp-admin 404

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress site is hosted  like this `http://domain.com`. And we are accessing through a sub folder /blog. So I have defined the home URL and site URL in wp-config.php and changed the site url in wp-options table as `http://domain.com/blog`. Everything is work fine except the wp-admin home page.  The wp-login page is getting perfectly(`http://domain.com/blog/wp-login.php`) but after giving the credentials the site is moving to the `http://domain.com/wp-admin` without /blog. So the result is 404 page. Can you suggest a solution for this?

How can set the home url for wp-admin? I mean after login the page should go to this `domain.com/blog/wp-admin` page.. How it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Same use to happen to me. Take a copy of your **database** and **template** folder, and apply a fresh WP install (with the automatically generated wp-config).

It could be the .htaccess, since after setting your Wordpress site up, you've changed directories, so the permalink structure gets messy, since it's still thinks you're using the old structure when in reality you changed folders.

Comment: Yes. How can set the home url for wp-admin? I mean after login the page should go to this http://domain.com/blog/wp-admin page.. How it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move your site to a new location I suggest using the plugin 'WP migrate DB'. Undo what you have done thus far, so you can log back into your admin again. Install the plugin and enter your new values for URL and file path. In your case this would be just adding '/blog' to the current ones. when you click 'export' you'll have a new database you can replace your current one with. Then move your files to /blog.

This plugin searches and replaces all occurrences of your site URL and file path with your new values, including serialized data fields.

Answer (score 0):

did you update the `home` in wp-options table. This is probably at 36 of option_id

Comment: just go to the wp-options table in database (or phpMyAdmin) then go to the next page (using pagination). At the option_id 36 you'd get option_name "home" ... change that URL too. I fall in such issue almost 3 years ago and got the solution doing it.

Comment: Nothing happened. Again redirected to the http://domain.com/wp-admin without the subfolder /blog

Comment: Is there any other way to change the http://domain.com/wp-admin to http://domain.com/blog/wp-admin

Comment: It should work, I just tested now. At first, I could see only homepage but /wp-admin redirect to earlier URL. Then I just change two row of the wp-options table -  siteurl and home -  then got fixed. Moreover, I don't think so that defining Site and Home URL is necessary once you update the database. Please try to follow my steps exactly.

Comment: Hey.. I have did like that But in the case of wp-login -> wp-admin dashboard it doesn't work.

Comment: what happens at dashboard

Comment: The dashboard URL is taken as domain.com/wp-admin. so we get 404 page. when manually add /blog(like domain.com/blog/wp-admin) it correctly fit and get the dashboard.

Comment: after login, go Settings > General and update two fields 1. WordPress Address (URL) 2. Site Address (URL)

Comment: there is no more things or steps remained according to wordpress instructions. You may check again http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 0):

I think your database table url are not updated. Use below code to update db table urls:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.OLDURL', 'http://www.NEWURL') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.OLDURL','http://www.NEWURL');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.OLDURL', 'http://www.NEWURL');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.OLDURL','http://www.NEWURL');
```

And then check your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue with the permalinks. What I suggest you is to take a look at your phpmyadmin and go to wp-options. You might see the url of the blog and see if it matches what you want or go to `wp-config.php` and see if it is correctly written.

Also, you can change the permalinks scheme to see if it works.

See this https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL